# GeoWebCache: Layer is not served by a WMS backend

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geowebcache

I try to get legends for my layers in a little GIS application while using GeoWebCache.
Since I turned GeoWebCache in GeoServer on I do not get the legend image for my layers anymore.
I looked around and found this thread here: [How to get WMS LegendGraphics using Geoserver and GeoWebCache?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21912/how-to-get-wms-legendgraphics-using-geoserver-and-geowebcache). However, my attempt to set the 'legendURL' by using '...LAYER" + map.layers[6].params["LAYERS"])' fails. The only thing I am getting back is that 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'mapPanel.layers[6].params').

Can somebody help me here? The application is temporarily [here](http://www2.dmu.dk/atmosphericenvironment/LPDV/suite_inWork.html) available.

Thanks a lot,
Thomas

Comment: do you have 7 layers in your map?

Comment: I do have six available to be shown in the map and a seventh is used for the geolocation request. However, when I request the names of the layers then I get only six answers and not seven.

Comment: I'm pretty sure arrays number from 0 in javascript so you probably mean map.layers[5].params...

Comment: Alright, I replaced the 6 by a 5 and now the error message is a bad request (400)

http://dmugeoweb2.dmu.dk:9090/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1$REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_xml&LAYER=LPDV:LG_NO2Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: It might be important to mention that the layers to be shown are all layer groups, where the legend depends on the scale of the map.